# Can I pass values in the body root instead of through inArguments with Marketing Cloud Custom Activity

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, custom-activity

We built a custom activity POST in Journey Builder. It works as designed, connects to our API and passes field:value pairs like a typical REST POST. However it works because we hard code values in the config.json body for testing purpose. The actual values we want to read are being passed as inArguments.

```
"arguments": {
    "execute": {
        "inArguments":[],
        "outArguments": [],
        "url": "https://myurl.m.pipedream.net/",
        "verb": "POST",
        "body": "{\"de\": \"SurveyURLs\",\"emailKey\": \"demo@company.com\",\"surveyId\": \"SV_cWUnMW\",\"firstName\": \"Jane\",\"lastName\": \"Smith\"}",
        "headers": "{\"x-api-key\": \"xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx\"}",
        "timeout": 20000,
        "retryCount": 5,
        "retryDelay": 10000
    }
},
```

The dynamic payload built in customActivity.js adds the field:value pairs to the inArguments array as seems to be standard practice. And we do see the values passed along as expected in the inArguments.

```
payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
  "subscriberKey": "{{Contact.Key}}",
  "surveyID": surveyID,
  "de":de,
  "firstName":"{{Event.AutomationAud-myInstance.firstName}}",
  "lastName":"{{Event.AutomationAud-myInstance.lastName}}",
  "accountID":"{{Event.AutomationAud-myInstance.accountID}}"
}];
```

Our API isn't built to parse through inArguments for the payload. Is it possible to attach the data to body instead of body{inArguments[]} ?

We have tried different combinations of: payload['arguments'].execute.body =[{JSON}];
with hope that the payload would pass along in the post body, but the activity does not pass validation. Combinations that do pass validation fail to build the POST when a contact goes through the journey; Hard Error.